# Error al instalar módulo de nodejs en EC2 Amazon con ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nodejs, ec2, npm

Estoy intentando instalar un módulo de `nodejs` en una instancia de Amazon EC2 cuando ejecuto `ppm install markdown-pdf` obtengo el siguiente error:

```
> phantomjs@1.9.19 install /home/ubuntu/fermat-org/api-server/node_modules/markdown-pdf/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Download already available at /home/ubuntu/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

npm ERR! weird error 134
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Tengo `node v0.12.25` y `npm 1.3.10`

Comment: que version de Ubuntu esta usando

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow quizas quiera echar un vistazo a esta pagina http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @AngelAngel Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, Release: 14.04, Codename: trusty

Comment: hace algun tiempo el equipo de Debian decidio renombrar node to nodejs https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/70

Comment: probaste de borrar /home/ubuntu/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2  y luego reintentar?

Comment: @rnrneverdies genio me funciono, elimine el modulo y reintente y genial todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminé el archivo ubicado `/home/ubuntu/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2`, luego instalé de nuevo el paquete `npm install markdown-pdf` y funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: Deberias seleccionar esto como tu respuesta.

Answer (score -1):

Hace algún tiempo el equipo de *Debian* decidió renombrar [`node` a `nodejs`](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/issues/70).

Mirando esto:

```
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
```

Usted puede tratar de instalarlo mediante el gestor de paquetes:

> sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy

Comment: ya tengo la ultima versión, cuando ejecuto `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` obtengo,  `nodejs-legacy is already the newest version`.

Comment: @German me alegra que lo solucionaras, veo que rnrneverdies te dio la solucion Saludos